# Unable to Read SHA1 File while Deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, capistrano

When attempting to deploy via Capistrano I am getting the following errors. This is happened on a repo that I've been working on for more than a year and everything has been going smooth during the past.

Any ideas on how to fix the repo?

```
error: unable to find 3b1ab2a2fa39f4ffc4a53a7888223522195e2506
error: unable to read sha1 file of .gitignore (3b1ab2a2fa39f4ffc4a53a7888223522195e2506)
error: unable to find 6cb9767572171070c88d5792022edd855f63e57d
error: unable to read sha1 file of Gemfile (6cb9767572171070c88d5792022edd855f63e57d)
error: unable to find 63303cc69f301a4d691cd4a2fb95005996a1d5fd
error: unable to read sha1 file of app/controllers/mobile_controller.rb (63303cc69f301a4d691cd4a2fb95005996a1d5fd)
error: unable to find 57ca529579101e75240e78985419a73c89a6ba44
```

..

```
Checking out files: 100% (5634/5634), done.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'db369d7ee2aa96750ff1fd61f53ec049038a74eb'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing /tmp/deploy-cache/ fixed problem.